# Pig Register - cannot find jar file in hdfs

Tags: apache-pig

I wanner to write a pig script which should load a jar file. The following is my code:

Register /aa/bb/cc/ex.jar

I run the pig by hui and the jar file exists in the hdfs. However, it always remind that the file doesn't exist.

I am not sure if I use correct method to register a jar file from hdfs. Could you please give me ideas?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: are you running pig in local or mapreduce mode?

Answer (score 3):

According to 
http://pig.apache.org/docs/r0.12.0/basic.html#register, you have to specify a full location uri for the jar file. For example,

```
register hdfs://namenode:port/aa/bb/cc/ex.jar;
```